# Where is podfile in flutter for phone firebase auth?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, cocoapods, flutter

I am trying to set up phone authentication with firebase.
Inside firebase guidelines there is this part for iOS

from here
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth

> Include the following pods in your Podfile:
>
> `pod 'Firebase/Auth'`

But I cannot find Podfile in my app directory.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to run the app on iOS Simulator once. Then the Podfile was created in `ios/Podfile`