# flutter project not running in IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am getting errors when trying to run the flutter app in IOS. First I tried to run a project that was made in Windows for android and it worked but when I run the same project for IOS it doesn't work and shows the error of pod files as below:

```
Unable to load contents of file list:
'/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist'

Unable to load contents of file list: 
'/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist'

Unable to load contents of file list:
 '/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist'

/Users/shikha/Desktop/vodome/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.h:1:9:
 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
```

even if I make a new project it doesn't work in IOS and is showing different errors like above and below:

[image]

and the error keeps changing like this.
please if anyone can help me with this, let me know.
thank you

Comment: have you installed `cocoapods`? If yes then go to ios directory and run `pod install`.

Comment: i have tried that but still not working

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to your project then
run command in terminal:

1. `cd ios`
2. `pod install`

it will update your podfile

Comment: I have tried pod install but the error still remains.

Comment: Have you run `flutter clean` command ?  , then delete podfile.lock, if it does not work then  run `pod repo update`

Comment: follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51599686/flutter-podfile-and-pods-folders-not-created-in-ios-directory)

Answer (score 1):

trying to following command.

1. cd ios
2. remove Podfile.lock
3. pod deintegrate; pod install