# How to solve : error running pod install in mac

Tags: flutter, dart

when i run my Flutter app in Mac i get this issue :

````
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `admob_flutter` from `.symlinks/plugins/admob_flutter/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `apple_sign_in` from `.symlinks/plugins/apple_sign_in/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
    cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '8.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
    firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '8.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
    firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_messaging` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_messaging/ios`
    firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '8.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_storage` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_storage/ios`
    firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '8.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `geolocator` from `.symlinks/plugins/geolocator/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `google_sign_in` from `.symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `image_cropper` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_cropper/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `image_picker` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `location_permissions` from `.symlinks/plugins/location_permissions/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `path_provider` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `sqflite` from `.symlinks/plugins/sqflite/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `url_launcher` from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher/ios`

    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_5_9_a.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/5/9/a/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/8.8.0/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.5.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_d_4_0.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/d/4/0/GoogleSignIn/6.0.1/GoogleSignIn.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_3_7_4.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/7/4/TOCropViewController/2.6.0/TOCropViewController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_f_4_e.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/f/4/e/FMDB/2.7.5/FMDB.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/f/4/e/FMDB/2.7.5/FMDB.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/f/4/e/FMDB/2.7.5/FMDB.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/7/4/TOCropViewController/2.6.0/TOCropViewController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_6_3_6.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/3/6/FirebaseAuth/8.5.0/FirebaseAuth.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_3_c_c.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/c/c/FirebaseStorage/8.5.0/FirebaseStorage.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_8_b_d.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/8.5.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_9_f.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/9/f/FirebaseFirestore/8.5.0/FirebaseFirestore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/3/6/FirebaseAuth/8.3.0/FirebaseAuth.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_8_4.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.5.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.4.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.4.1/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.4.3/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.5.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.4.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.4.1/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.4.3/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.5.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_c_e_3.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/e/3/GTMSessionFetcher/1.6.1/GTMSessionFetcher.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/e/3/GTMSessionFetcher/1.5.0/GTMSessionFetcher.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/e/3/GTMSessionFetcher/1.6.0/GTMSessionFetcher.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/e/3/GTMSessionFetcher/1.6.1/GTMSessionFetcher.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/8.3.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.4.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.4.1/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.4.3/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.5.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_8_3_c.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/3/c/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/8.5.0/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/8.5.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/8.4.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/8.3.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/8.2.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/8.1.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/8.0.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_2_d_6.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/2/d/6/FirebaseMessaging/8.5.0/FirebaseMessaging.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/c/c/FirebaseStorage/8.3.0/FirebaseStorage.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/2/d/6/FirebaseMessaging/8.3.0/FirebaseMessaging.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_2_f_7.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/2/f/7/FirebaseInstallations/8.5.0/FirebaseInstallations.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.4.0library.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/8/7/gRPC-C++/1.28.2/gRPC-C++.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/8/7/gRPC-C++/1.28.0/gRPC-C++.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/8/7/gRPC-C++/1.28.2/gRPC-C++.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/8/7/gRPC-C++/1.28.2/gRPC-C++.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_9_1_0.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/9/1/0/gRPC-Core/1.39.0/gRPC-Core.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update

    ――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

    ### Command

    ```
    /usr/local/bin/pod install --verbose
    ```

    ### Report

    * What did you do?

    * What did you expect to happen?

    * What happened instead?


    ### Stack

    ```
       CocoaPods : 1.10.2
            Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]
        RubyGems : 3.0.3
            Host : Mac OS X 10.15.6 (19G2021)
           Xcode : 12.3 (12C33)
             Git : git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)
    Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
    Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
    ```

    ### Plugins

    ```
    cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
    cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
    cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
    cocoapods-stats       : 1.1.0
    cocoapods-trunk       : 1.5.0
    cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
    ```

    ### Podfile

    ```ruby
    #Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
    platform :ios, '10.0'

    # CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
    ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

    project 'Runner', {
      'Debug' => :debug,
      'Profile' => :release,
      'Release' => :release,
    }

    def flutter_root
      generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
      unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
        raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
      end

      File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
        matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
        return matches[1].strip if matches
      end
      raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
    end

    require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

    flutter_ios_podfile_setup

    target 'Runner' do
      use_frameworks!
      use_modular_headers!

      flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
    end

    post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
      end
    end
    ```

    ### Error

    ```
    JSON::ParserError - 416: unexpected token at '"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/round_rob'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/json.rb:61:in `from_json'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:742:in `from_string'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:716:in `from_file'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:186:in `specification'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:58:in `block in specification_name'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:56:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:56:in `specification_name'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods-
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    ```

    ――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

    [!] Oh no, an error occurred.

    Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
    https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=416%3A+unexpected+token+at+%27%22src%2Fcore%2Fext%2Ffilters%2Fclient_channel%2Flb_policy%2Fround_rob%27&type=Issues

    If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
    https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

    Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
    https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

    Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

    Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
    Found no similar issues. To create a new issue, please visit:
    https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues/new

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
````

i try delete `podfile.lock` and run this :

`pod install`  or `pod update`

i get this issue

```
Analyzing dependencies
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '8.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '8.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '8.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '8.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

### Command


/usr/local/bin/pod install


### Report

* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?


### Stack

   CocoaPods : 1.10.2
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3
        Host : Mac OS X 10.15.6 (19G2021)
       Xcode : 12.3 (12C33)
         Git : git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/


### Plugins


cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.1.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.5.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0


### Podfile

ruby
#Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end


### Error


JSON::ParserError - 416: unexpected token at '"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/round_rob'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/json.rb:61:in `from_json'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:742:in `from_string'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:716:in `from_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:186:in `specification'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'


――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=416%3A+unexpected+token+at+%27%22src%2Fcore%2Fext%2Ffilters%2Fclient_channel%2Flb_policy%2Fround_rob%27&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
Found no similar issues. To create a new issue, please visit:
https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues/new
```

my Packeg **pubspec.yaml**

```
environment:
 sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
 flutter:
   sdk: flutter

 # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
 # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
 cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
 flutter_test:
   sdk: flutter
 age: ^0.0.1

 #Firebase Package
 firebase_auth: ^3.0.1
 firebase_core: ^1.4.0
 firebase_storage: ^10.0.1
 cloud_firestore: ^2.4.0
 firebase_messaging: ^10.0.4
 admob_flutter: ^2.0.0-nullsafety.1
 google_sign_in: ^5.0.5
 font_awesome_flutter: ^9.1.0
 feather_icons_flutter: ^4.7.4
 line_awesome_flutter: ^1.0.1
 provider: ^5.0.0
 intl: ^0.17.0
 http: ^0.13.3
 url_launcher: ^6.0.9
 shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
 universal_html: ^2.0.4
 cached_network_image: ^3.0.0
 image_picker: ^0.7.2
 image_cropper: ^1.3.1
 flutter_spinkit: ^4.1.2+1
 curved_navigation_bar: ^0.3.7
 flutter_styled_toast:
 select_form_field:
 rflutter_alert: ^1.0.8
 geolocator: ^5.1.3
 simple_animations: ^2.2.1
 slide_popup_dialog: ^0.0.2
 flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.4.0
 quiz_view: ^1.0.3
 motion_tab_bar: ^0.1.5
 fading_edge_scrollview: ^2.0.0
 pinch_zoom: ^0.1.0
 percent_indicator: ^3.0.1
 flutter_intro: ^2.3.0
```

Flutter Doctor its all good

help me plz :(

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem a few days ago and the solution for me was this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60620770/13842814

Comment: thanks for reply , don't work for me :( when i run pod install i get same issue

Answer (score 0):

I am using **Apple M1 chip**. I tried with below step and working for me.

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

then

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

For terminal you have to enable Right click => Get info => **Open using Rosetta**

[image]

For Android Studio You also need to clear caches

> File => Invalidate caches / Restart..

[image]