# CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio, dart, cocoapods

I have tried few solutions:

1. deleting podfile.lock and rebuilding with pod install --repo-update
2. delete all the pods files and setup pod from scratch
3. source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/' before my target 'Runner' do

But nothing has worked. Need help!

This Error occurs only when I try to open Android Studio from UI. When I open Android Studio from terminal this error doesn't occur.

I'm currently using Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1

My podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
'Debug' => :debug,
'Profile' => :release,
'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..',  'Flutter',     'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod     install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
end

File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
return matches[1].strip if matches
end
raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'

target 'Runner' do
use_frameworks!
use_modular_headers!

flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
 end
end
```

The error that was thrown during flutter run:

```
CocoaPods' output:
↳
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
    WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
    Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:105:in `markdown_podfile'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:30:in `report'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:205:in `podfile'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:160:in `verify_podfile_exists!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
```

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73370533/4641505

Answer (score 5):

Have same problem, i closed android studio, and opened it from the terminal, seems to fix the problem.

```
open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
```

Comment: check your address called

Answer (score 0):

same issue that i faced also, I just share the way to open from jetbrain toolbox

- Intellij

```
open /Users/[username]/Applications/JetBrains\ Toolbox/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ Ultimate.app
```

- Android Studio

```
open /Users/[username]/Applications/JetBrains\ Toolbox/Android\ Studio\ Canary.app
```